# Making pie charts with no axis numbering/ticks in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been learning my way through ggplot2, and I've made it to using polar coordinates and making pie charts and I've run into a bit of trouble.

I want to make a pie chart that has no axis numbering or ticks. A sample of code I have that I thought should work is:

```
data = data.frame(Category = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Value = runif(4))
ggplot(data, aes(0, weight = Value, fill = Category)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = NA) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = NA) +
  geom_bar(binwidth = 1) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  scale_fill_brewer(pal = "Set1")
```

This code gives me the error:

```
Error in if (ends_apart < 0.05) { : argument is of length zero
```

Omitting the breaks argument in the scale_y_continuous function results in a successful plot, except with numbering and tick marks on the radius of the pie chart. Omitting the coord_polar (and leaving the breaks argument in scale_y_continuous) function results in a stacked bar chart without x or y numbering or tick marks.

I've found some solutions that involve changing tick mark options, and those should be a fine workaround, but I was curious as to why I'm getting this error.

As a side note: I've uninstalled and reinstalled ggplot2 to ensure that I have the latest version and that the checksums all match up.

Edit: To clarify, what I'm after is something like:

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTW9H.png)

except without the numbering on the pie chart.

Comment: The latest version of ggplot2 should not be accepting the abbreviation `pal` in `scale_fill_brewer`, so I'm dubious that you have the latest version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x = factor(0),y = Value,fill = Category)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "fill") +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set1') + 
    coord_polar(theta = "y") + 
    opts(axis.ticks = theme_blank(),
             axis.text.y = theme_blank(),
             axis.text.x = theme_blank())
```

**Note**: Since version 0.9.2 `opts` has been [replaced](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html) by `theme`:

```
+ theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the workaround I was referring to. I believe the weight and y aesthetic arguments work the same in this context. What was puzzling me was if I build a stacked bar chart with

ggplot(data, aes(0, y = Value, fill = Category)) +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = NA) +
      scale_y_continuous(breaks = NA) +
      geom_bar(binwidth = 1)

it works fine. Then adding in polar coordinates with 

    last_plot() + coord_polar(theta = "y")

gives me the error above. It just seems strange that changing coordinate would cause this error.

Comment: @tkmckenzie I can't reproduce those errors, but then again, as I note above I'm actually using the latest version, while I strongly suspect that you are not.

Comment: I just took a look to make sure I have the latest version installed, and you're correct, I was using R 2.13, so I upgraded and this problem was taken care of. Thanks for your help!